# Resultados conflitantes passando um Array como parâmetro

Tags: c, array

A ideia é criar uma função que, dado um Array/vetor unidimensional, devolve o número de elementos presentes nesse vetor/Array:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX 6
#define TXT 20

int arraySize(char array[][TXT]);

int main(){
    char array[MAX][TXT]={"Test0", "Test1", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test3"};

    printf("\n Main: [%d]\n Func: [%d]\n\n", sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]), arraySize(array));

    return 0;
}

int arraySize(char array[][TXT]){
    return sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

A questão, aqui, é que na função main funciona perfeitamente, portanto, quando feito em uma função auxiliar, o resultado, mesmo utilizando a mesma lógica, dá incorreto; gostaria de saber se alguém consegue me auxiliar nesse dilema, creio ter a ver com o tipo de passagem de parâmetro, mas tentei usar ponteiros e o erro persiste.

OBS.: Utilizar a constante MAX não é uma opção, uma vez que, não necessariamente, saberei o valor de MAX; a ideia é, justamente, descobrir o numero de elementos desse vetor para, por exemplo, utiliza-lo como argumento de um iterador.

Comment: Seu array é de tamanho estático então ele vai sempre ter o mesmo tamanho em memória. Não faz diferença se vc está usando a memória ou não, vc alocou uma matriz de char[MAX][TXT]. Para fazer oq vc está querendo vc deve marcar quais endereços do array que vc não está utilizando, por ex. marcando NULL. Aí vc muda a sua função de contagem para que ela conte a quantidade de strings válidas no array.

Comment: Eu pensei nessa possibilidade, a questão é, do jeito que está, executar a linha `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` dentro da main e fora dela com o mesmo vetor retorna resultados diferentes. No exemplo de execução acima ele retorna 6 dentro da main (numero correto de elementos presentes no vetor) e na função `int arraySize(char array[][TXT])` ele retorna 0. Isso ocorre pois dentro da main `sizeof(array)` retorna 120 (20 * o numero de elementos do vetor), contudo a mesma função executada na função `int arraySize(char array[][TXT])` retorna 4,

Comment: seguindo a lógica de execução, a main fara 120/20=6 enquanto a outra função fará 4/20=0, a questão é por que a outra função retorna 4 quando faço `sizeof(array)`

Comment: Então, sizeof é um operador que te retorna o valor durante a COMPILAÇÃO e não durante a EXECUÇÃO. Seu código na função arraySize define uma outra variável com nome array de tipo diferente do que array em main. Daí o compilador n sabe qual tamanho de array na função (pq vc definiu o tipo de array em char[][MAX]) e te retorna um valor padrão de 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu sei, é impossível de fazer oq vc está tentando fazer em C sem algum tipo de acesso aos dados do array, como por exemplo contar até o primeiro valor NULL. Do jeito que está implementado, vc espera que para cada chamada de função com um array de tamanho diferente se retorne um valor diferente, porém seria necessário instanciar uma nova implementação da função para aquele novo tipo, recompilando o valor de `sizeof` no retorno.

A solução genérica de ter uma variável do tipo `char [][TXT]` como parâmetro não funciona pq quando vc chama `arraySize(array)`, o tipo da variável `array` decai de `char [MAX][TXT]` para `char*[TXT]` para que a função arraySize tenha uma única implementação. Logo parte da informação sobre o tamanho do vetor é perdida e quando vc pede o valor de `sizeof(array)`, ele simplesmente retorna 4 bytes pq esse é o tamanho de um ponteiro na sua plataforma.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define MAX 6
#define TXT 20

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t array_size(T (&a)[N])
{
    return sizeof(T) * N;
}

int main()
{
    char array[MAX][TXT];
    std::cout << sizeof(array)      << "/" << sizeof(*array)     << '\n'
              << array_size(array)  << "/" << array_size(*array) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Como templates só existem em C++ e não em C, postei uma alternativa à sua implementação em C++.

Note que no fim das contas é só uma maneira mais elaborada de usar o operador `sizeof`. Sem ponteiros e alocação dinâmica, não tem como fugir muito disso pq de qualquer maneira vc fica preso no fato de que os valores são computados durante a compilação. Para calcular o tamanho de vetores em execução vc precisa de usar estruturas de dados mais complexas com variáveis adicionais para contagem e alocação dinâmica, como por exemplo um [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).